# Reactjs app running inside an iframe, sizing issues

Tags: reactjs, iframe, scrollbar

I have a reactjs application which when run on a browser is shown smoothly and fits inside the browser window (no need to scroll in order to see the bottom of the page). 
In my company we are building several of those single page apps and there is a team which developed the infrastructure to navigate between those apps, they used a top navigation bar with iframes, problem is that my app running inside the iframe is not quite the same, the user needs to scroll down and up to see the entire application as opposed to running without the iframe.

How can I make my app fit to height of the iframe?

Comment: What is the CSS for the project? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: I think I found the problematic area, I have a loading overlay component, which its style has height: window.innerHeight - when I remove this binding of height, the app looks better inside the iframe, however the overlay is shrinking and adapting to the content displayed instead of filling the entire iframe.